# mvn sonar:sonar not generating dashboard data

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We use maven for building our projects.

I implemented the configuration mentioned in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven to analyze the project using sonar.

Snapshot of my `.m2/settings.xml`

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.207.67.95/XE</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>sonarqube</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>sonarqube</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.jdbc.driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
            <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>sonar</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

When i run `mvn sonar:sonar` from the directory containing my `pom.xml`, it shows build success.

I checked the dashboard, the project shows up, and the LOC shown is empty.
Dashboard shows up no issues.

Output from `mvn sonar:sonar`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx 2.2.0.29-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) @ xxxx ---
[INFO] Sonar version: 3.6.2
[INFO] [15:18:16.984] Load batch settings
[INFO] [15:18:17.043] User cache: /home/jsaluja/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [15:18:17.048] Install plugins
[INFO] [15:18:17.589] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [15:18:17.596] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.207.67.95/XE
[INFO] [15:18:19.296] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [15:18:21.830] Load project settings
[INFO] [15:18:21.858] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [15:18:22.003] -------------  Scan xxxx
[INFO] [15:18:22.008] Load module settings
[INFO] [15:18:22.607] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[INFO] [15:18:22.625] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [15:18:22.625]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [15:18:22.660] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [15:18:22.728] Compare to previous analysis (2013-08-08)
[INFO] [15:18:22.750] Compare over 5 days (2013-08-03, analysis of 2013-08-07 12:55:06.0)
[INFO] [15:18:22.763] Compare over 30 days (2013-07-09, analysis of 2013-08-07 12:55:06.0)
[INFO] [15:18:22.890] Base dir: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx
[INFO] [15:18:22.890] Working dir: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/target/sonar
[INFO] [15:18:22.890] Binary dirs: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/target/classes
[INFO] [15:18:22.890] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [15:18:22.894] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [15:18:22.894] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[INFO] [15:18:22.894] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:22.894] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [15:18:22.894] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:22.895] parsing /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [15:18:22.898] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [15:18:22.898] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:22.898] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [15:18:22.898] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [15:18:22.898] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:22.901] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [15:18:22.901] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:23.209] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 308 ms
[INFO] [15:18:23.209] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:23.236] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 27 ms
[INFO] [15:18:23.236] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:23.241] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
[INFO] [15:18:23.241] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:23.253] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 12 ms
[INFO] [15:18:23.253] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [15:18:23.805] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 552 ms
[INFO] [15:18:23.805] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [15:18:23.809] Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
[INFO] [15:18:23.809] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [15:18:24.112] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [15:18:24.287] Store results in database
[INFO] [15:18:24.336] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/a.b.c.d.e:xxxx
[INFO] [15:18:24.337] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [15:18:24.337] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [15:18:24.387] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [15:18:24.398] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-07-11 and 2013-08-07
[INFO] [15:18:24.400] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-08-09 and 2013-07-11
[INFO] [15:18:24.401] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-08-14 and 2012-08-09
[INFO] [15:18:24.402] -> Delete data prior to: 2008-08-14
[INFO] [15:18:24.404] -> Clean xxxx [id=10080]
[INFO] [15:18:24.409] <- Clean snapshot 13758
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.637s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 08 15:18:24 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/277M
```

I could independently run sonar runner from the same directory using `sonar-project.properties` and dashboard shows up data, and a bunch of issues.

Output from sonar runner:

```
 ~/sonar-runner-2.3/bin/sonar-runner 
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.6.0_21 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/jsaluja/sonar-runner-2.3/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.6.2
15:19:14.377 INFO  - Load batch settings
15:19:14.440 INFO  - User cache: /home/jsaluja/.sonar/cache
15:19:14.444 INFO  - Install plugins
15:19:14.944 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
15:19:14.952 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.207.67.95/XE
15:19:16.300 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
15:19:18.517 INFO  - Load project settings
15:19:18.548 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
15:19:18.682 INFO  - -------------  Scan xxxx
15:19:18.688 INFO  - Load module settings
15:19:19.295 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
15:19:19.314 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
15:19:19.314 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
15:19:19.355 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
15:19:19.439 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2013-08-08)
15:19:19.463 INFO  - Compare over 5 days (2013-08-03, analysis of 2013-08-08 14:38:22.472)
15:19:19.478 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2013-07-09, analysis of 2013-08-08 14:38:22.472)
15:19:19.647 INFO  - Base dir: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx
15:19:19.647 INFO  - Working dir: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/.sonar
15:19:19.648 INFO  - Source dirs: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/src
15:19:19.648 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
15:19:19.691 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
15:19:20.048 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 357 ms
15:19:20.048 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
15:19:20.115 INFO  - Java AST scan...
15:19:22.213 INFO  - Java AST scan done: 2098 ms
15:19:22.354 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 2306 ms
15:19:22.354 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
15:19:22.355 INFO  - parsing /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/.sonar/build/surefire-reports
15:19:22.355 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 1 ms
15:19:22.355 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
15:19:22.355 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
15:19:22.360 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
15:19:22.635 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 280 ms
15:19:22.636 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
15:19:22.637 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
15:19:22.648 INFO  - Checkstyle configuration: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/.sonar/checkstyle.xml
15:19:23.990 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 1353 ms
15:19:24.001 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 1365 ms
15:19:24.001 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor...
15:19:24.004 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3...
15:19:24.024 INFO  - Java version: 1.5
15:19:24.066 INFO  - PMD configuration: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/.sonar/pmd.xml
15:19:27.017 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3 done: 3013 ms
15:19:27.110 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor done: 3109 ms
15:19:27.110 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
15:19:27.363 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 253 ms
15:19:27.363 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor...
15:19:27.638 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 275 ms
15:19:27.638 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
15:19:27.654 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 16 ms
15:19:27.655 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
15:19:27.660 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
15:19:27.660 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
15:19:27.674 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 14 ms
15:19:27.674 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
15:19:27.677 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
15:19:27.677 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 3 ms
15:19:28.164 INFO  - Execute decorators...
15:19:31.041 INFO  - Store results in database
15:19:31.214 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/a.b.c.d.xxxx
15:19:31.216 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
15:19:31.230 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
15:19:31.279 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
15:19:31.288 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-07-11 and 2013-08-07
15:19:31.289 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-08-09 and 2013-07-11
15:19:31.289 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-08-14 and 2012-08-09
15:19:31.289 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2008-08-14
15:19:31.292 INFO  - -> Clean xxxx [id=11882]
15:19:31.296 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 13716
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 17.946s
Final Memory: 20M/732M
INFO: --------------------------------------------
```

The dashboard screenshot for the mvn and sonar runner executed for the same project

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2TK6N3XnvavRmdrX0ZYb2V3Q0k/edit?usp=sharing

Red one shows output for mvn - no LOC
Green one shows output for sonar runner - LOC and issues identified

What am i missing with mvn configuration ?

Comment: Show the output from mvn sonar:sonar.

Comment: tdrury, just added the mvn output to original question

Comment: when you run via maven vs. sonar runner are you sending data to two different sonar instances?  Or sending to same instance with different  project IDs?  Or sending as same project ID?

Comment: Assuming you're sending to the same sonar w/ same project ID, when you run via sonar runner you have good data, right?  Then  you run via maven.  Does that snapshot in sonar have 0 LOC/no issues?

Comment: tdrury, I ran mvn sonar:sonar first, and it showed up 0 LOC / no issues. Then i created sonar project properties file and used sonar runner for same project, and it showed up data. The dashboard screenshot can be found here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2TK6N3XnvavRmdrX0ZYb2V3Q0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This probably doesn't help much since you probably already realize this, but when running from maven it doesn't appear that it is finding your source directories.  I compared your output to mine and mine logs which source directory it's using. Additionally, the source import is 0ms compared to 357ms for the working method.

Comment: any reason why the source directories could no be found. can you share  your pom configuration

Comment: Sorry, I can't really share my POM configuration because I run sonar via Jenkins which, in turn, just runs sonar:sonar goal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that sonar does not find any class files

```
15:19:27.677 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
```

Did you run

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

before `mvn sonar:sonar` as [recommended](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-RecommendedWay)?  `mvn sonar:sonar` will not compile the source code anymore (I think since sonar 3.6).

Comment: yes, i did follow the sequence 
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: the project coverage is shown as 0% in the logs of both mvn and sonar runner. 

mvn log
...
'[INFO] [15:18:23.809] Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.'
...


sonar runner log
...
15:19:27.677 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no directories with classes.
...

Comment: @jsaluja If you use maven 3 be sure to use the sonar-maven-plugin version 2.1 as described [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-HowtoFixVersionofMavenPlugin). I noticed in the logs that you use version 2.0.

Comment: I tried with version 2.1 configured in the pom as well. Same behavior, empty dashboard... 
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>

Comment: Your maven output is missing the `Source dirs: /home/jsaluja/0801/frontend/yyyy/xxxx/src` log statment. I think you have to check why the source directory is not recognized.

Comment: I noticed that mvn sonar:sonar is generating sonar-pom.xml. I noticed a source entry in the sonar-pom.xml which is incorrect  <build>
<sourceDirectory>/home/jsaluja/0821/frontend/yyyy/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>. This is incorrect. Our code resides at /home/jsaluja/0821/frontend/yyyy/src/. How and where do we configure the source path for mvn sonar:sonar